# How to parse pdfs with java, which where generated with latex (to get the structure like chapters or sections)

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, latex, structure

I have a question. I'm trying to extract structured text from pdf documents. Since pdfs usually don't have structure, I thought I could start parsing pdfs generated with latex, which should have some structure.

Do you know there are any patterns in pdfs gernerated with Latex I could use for parsing the pdf?

Comment: While I doubt you'll find some really good patterns, chances might rise if you more strictly define the environment. Last time I was in contact with LaTeX there were different paths for PDF creation from LaTeX: via the TeX device independant files, i.e. LaTeX -> DVI -> [PS ->] PDF, and directly LaTeX -> PDF. If there are patterns, they surely are different for those different paths. The patterns additionally might depend on the versions of the software involved.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [PDF Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html), for parsing text out of PDF documents. Or you could use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which offers parsing for multiple document types, with a standard interface (might be overkill). I would not recommend trying to do this by hand .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I took a look at iText, PDFBox and Apache Tika. I was able to parse the content out of pdf files. The Problem is that I want to build something like a tree, where the conent is structured into sections and subsections etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Commercial Solution Infty Reader**

http://www.sciaccess.net/en/InftyReader/index.html

In the trial mode, the recognition is limited to one page 
each time, and 5 pages per day.

**With the terminal**

- quick and dirty solution, that will probably take a lot of try and error.

  1. your pdf must be parsable

     - `pdftotext 'your-file.pdf' your-file.txt`
  2. you need a pattern in your pdf (like a copyright on every slide)

     - `sed -n '/<PATTERN>/{n;n;n;p}' your-file.txt | awk '!x[$0]++' > your-file-structure.txt`
     - change `{n;n;n;p}` as it is currently printing `p` the next next next `n;n;n` line after your pattern
     - `awk '!x[$0]++'` deletes duplicates